# Adding military times together not working - JAVA

Tags: java, class, methods, time, clock

I'm trying to make a clock class in Java that will display military time, and my teacher has given us a ClockTester.java that uses our "engine" of a clock. I've gotten it to display correctly, but I'm having trouble adding time correctly.
It's all displayed in military time, so adding 12:00:00 and 15:00:00 should give me 03:00:00, not 27:00:00 like it is giving me... But I'm having trouble doing that.

Here are my math methods:

```
public void addHours(int h){
        int sum = this.hours + h;
        this.hours = (sum % 24);
        if((this.hours = (sum % 24)) > 23) //Keeps the hours within real boundaries
            this.hours -= 24;
    }

public void addMinutes(int m){
    int sum = this.mins + m;
    this.mins = (sum % 60);
    if((this.mins = (sum % 60)) > 59){  //Keeps the mins within real boundaries
        this.mins -= 60;
        this.addHours(sum % 60);
    }
}

public void addSeconds(int s){
    int sum = this.secs + s;
    this.secs = (sum % 60);
    if((this.secs = (sum % 60)) > 59){  //Keeps the secs within real boundaries
        this.secs -= 60;
        this.addMinutes(sum % 60);
    }
}
```

Please let me know if you need to see/know anything else to help me. Thanks.

Comment: So, when the sum of the `hour` exceeds 24, you need to subtract `24` from it (27 - 24 = 3).  Assuming that you're using 0-23 hours ;)

Comment: That's what the `%24` is for, @MadProgrammer !

Comment: @Docteur Sure, but it's not working, I went for the simplest possible solution available to me, like your answer though ;)

Comment: You use a `if` statement followed by your subtraction. It's better to use the modulo, in my opinion. Don't take my answer wrongly, we're here to help each other!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
this.hours += (sum % 24);
```

adds the result (for example, hours is 23, h is 5, so 28%24 = 4, hours = 23 + 4) to the hours.

You should try :

```
this.hours = (sum % 24);
```

You would do the same with minutes and seconds.

Comment: I'm trying everything and nothing is working. And I can't make these damn comments long enough to show you what's happening

Comment: Why are these `if` statements for? Have you tried without them?
Try doing the `if`s testing the value of "sum" instead.

Comment: Yeah, those are to make sure the extra minutes/seconds get added to the hours/minutes respectively.

Comment: Try this :
`if(sum > 59){ 
             int hoursToAdd = sum/60; // rounds
             this.addHours(hoursToAdd);
    }
`

Comment: I have <5 minutes to turn this in so... I guess it's just not going to work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75249/discussion-between-mazzone-and-docteur).